# NumberFormatException in Double.parseDouble()

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm trying to create a client/server application, the server ask the client to write two operands and then to choose an operation when the client choose the operation the server sends him back the result.

when I want to run my program I got this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1lient connectée"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at Server.main(Server.java:29)
```

this is my code :

**Server: **

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Server {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        try{
            DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(1234);
            byte[] sendBuffer = new byte [1024];
            byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket sendPacket, recvPacket;
            String reply = null;

            //Get the connection declaration from client
            recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuffer, recvBuffer.length);
            s.receive(recvPacket);
            System.out.println(new String(recvPacket.getData()));


            //Send the first message to client to write the first operand
            sendBuffer = "Entré n1 : ".getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuffer,sendBuffer.length,recvPacket.getAddress(),recvPacket.getPort());
            s.send(sendPacket);

            //Get the first operand
            recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuffer, recvBuffer.length);
            s.receive(recvPacket);
            double n1 = Double.parseDouble(new String(recvPacket.getData()));

            //Send the second message to client to write the second operand
            sendBuffer = "Donner n2 : ".getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.length, recvPacket.getAddress(), recvPacket.getPort());
            s.send(sendPacket);

            //Get the second operand
            recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuffer, recvBuffer.length);
            s.receive(recvPacket);
            double n2 = Double.parseDouble(new String(recvPacket.getData()));

            //Send the third message to client to choose the operation
            sendBuffer = "Choisir l'op : \n1-Addition \n2-Soustraction \n3-Multiplication \n4-Division \nVotre choix : ".getBytes();
            sendPacket= new DatagramPacket(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.length, recvPacket.getAddress(), recvPacket.getPort());
            s.send(sendPacket);

            //Get the number of operation
            recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuffer, recvBuffer.length);
            s.receive(recvPacket);
            reply = new String(recvPacket.getData());

            //Traitement
            String res = null;
            switch(reply){
                    case "1" :
                        res = String.valueOf(n1 + n2);
                        break;
                    case "2" :
                        res = String.valueOf(n1 - n2);
                        break;
                    case "3" :
                        res = String.valueOf(n1*n2);
                    case "4" :
                        res = (n2 == 0) ? "Division sue zéro" : String.valueOf(n1/n2);
                        break;
                    default :
                        res = "Erreur";
            }       

            //Send the result of the operation to the client
            sendBuffer = ("Resultat : "+res).getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.length, recvPacket.getAddress(), recvPacket.getPort());
            s.send(sendPacket);

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Client :**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Client {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws UnknownHostException{
        DatagramSocket s;
        byte[] sendBuffer = new byte[1024];
        byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket sendPacket, recvPacket;
        String reply = null;
        final InetAddress ADRSS = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        final int PORT = 1234;
        Scanner cn = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
             s = new DatagramSocket();

             //Declare connection to server
            sendBuffer = "Client connectée".getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.length, ADRSS, PORT);
            s.send(sendPacket);

            //Receive the first message from server
            recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuffer, recvBuffer.length);
            s.receive(recvPacket);
            System.out.println(new String(recvPacket.getData()));

            //Send the answer for the first Message to server (first operand)
            sendBuffer = cn.nextLine().getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.length, ADRSS, PORT);
            s.send(sendPacket);

            //Receive the second message from server
            recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuffer,recvBuffer.length);
            s.receive(recvPacket);
            System.out.println(new String(recvPacket.getData()));

            //Send the answer for the second Message to server (second operand)
            sendBuffer = cn.nextLine().getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.length, ADRSS, PORT);
            s.send(sendPacket);

            //Receive the third message from server
            recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuffer, recvBuffer.length);
            s.receive(recvPacket);
            System.out.println(new String(recvPacket.getData()));

            //Send the answer for the third Message to server (operation)
            sendBuffer = cn.nextLine().getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.length, ADRSS, PORT);
            s.send(sendPacket);

            //Receive the result from server (result of operation)
            recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuffer, recvBuffer.length);
            s.receive(recvPacket);
            System.out.println(new String(recvPacket.getData()));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The exception *name* is self-explanatory here, and it has nothing to do with clients or servers or UDP.

Answer (score 0):

`double n1 = Double.parseDouble(new String(recvPacket.getData()));`

This line is causing error, as you are sending String from the client and expecting double on the server. You are likely to face the same issue with the variable n2 as well. So, just treat them as String, and will be well.

Comment: For test I tried to send the number 1 from the client and then I got this error, the first message I'm sending from the client to the server which is String it works, but then the second message which must be a number when I send it I get from the error message that I tried to send this String : `1lient connectée`, it seems like the sendPacket kept the old message and then the first letter in the old message is replaced with the number I tried to send

Comment: I am not trying to be mean or trite, but I highly suggest you practice debugging a little more.  For one thing, the exception you got should have lead you straight to this line, look and find that link between the exception and code so you can do it next time, java exceptions are awesome troubleshooting tools!  Secondly log the new string to the console or a file before parsing it--your problem should become obvious quickly.  You may also want to pass "1", "1.0" and "1lient" to parseDouble and see what each does.